# Is grep part of coreutils? (If not, why?)

Tags: grep, coreutils

I have read in a few websites that grep comes with coreutils (e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_Utilities)

However, after building them, I noticed that grep is missing. I wonder if I built coreutils incorrectly. If grep is not part of coreutils, what is the rationale behind excluding it?

Comment: The wiki article you link to is about "Core Utilities", not coreutils. Its second sentence is "The scope of this article includes - but is not limited to - those utilities included with the GNU coreutils package." grep is not part of coreutils. I doubt there's any deep philosphical reason for grep being a separate package, that's just how it worked out in the early history of GNU.

Comment: There were even more packages before. "In 2003 these three packages of fileutils, shellutils, and textutils were combined into the current coreutils package. This greatly simplified the maintenance and management of this project." -- [`coreutils` FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Fileutils-shellutils-and-textutils). You'll also note that `findutils` is also a separate package. This is just an artefact of history, not particularly a packaging decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authoritative source would be http://www.gnu.org/software/software.html from the Free Software Foundation rather than the Wiki page cited in the accepted answer. On that page grep is listed as a separate piece of software.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the Arch Wiki page you refer to:

> The scope of this article includes - but is not limited to - those utilities included with the GNU coreutils package.

So even though the article covers `grep`, this doesn't automatically mean it's part of `coreutils`.

Moreover, [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) doesn't list `grep` among the tools in `coreutils`.